# @namedef and math mode

Tags: math-mode, macros, cross-referencing

I am trying to do something simple: I want to be able to store and retrieve texts and equations via labels. In particular, I want something like

```
\labelput{<label>}{<text>}  % sets the label. Associates text to label. 
\labelget{<label>}    % replaces by the text associated to label.
```

In the following MWE, the definitions work just fine in text mode. But it doesn't work in mathmode.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\labelput[2]{%
  \label{#1}%
  \@namedef{label@store@content@#1}{#2}%
  #2}
\newcommand\labelenvput[3]{%
  \@namedef{label@store@content@#2}{#3}%
  \begin{#1}%
  \label{#2}%
  #3%
  \end{#1}}
\newcommand\labelget[1]{\@nameuse{label@store@content@#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Test this first in \labelput{test1}{text mode}.

Does \labelget{test1} work?  % yes, it does

Test this again in math mode.

\begin{equation}\labelput{eq1}{e = mc^2}
\end{equation}

Now let us try to retrieve equation \ref{eq1} with
$\labelget{eq1}$   % the \ref works, but the \labelget fails silently


But the following works 
\labelenvput{equation}{eq2}{e = mc^3}

Retrieve
\[ \labelget{eq2} \]
\end{document}
```

So my questions

1. How to correctly use `\@namedef` in mathmode? Is there another command I should use instead?
2. Am I trying to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: The command `\labelretrieve` isn't defined. The command `\label` requires an anchor. In your case of `\labelput` there is no anchor.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: `\labelretrieve` is meant to be `\labelget`, made a mistake with "copying and pasting" from two different files. That the command `\label` requires an anchor has nothing to do with it, I think. Else it wouldn't even work in text mode.

Comment: Please try `Does \labelget{test1} work or \ref{test1}?  % yes, it does` and you will see the issue.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel I know that `\ref{test1}` will give me nothing in my MWE. But that's not the problem.

Comment: The main issue is solved by @egreg (as usual) :-) -- I thought it's just a point, you should know about.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: thanks. But as a rule I try to keep my MWE, well, minimal. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `\@namedef` is issued inside a group, so the control sequence disappears at the end of the group: every environment forms a group. Prefix `\@namedef` with `\global`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\labelput[2]{%
  \label{#1}%
  \global\@namedef{label@store@content@#1}{#2}%
  #2}
\newcommand\labelenvput[3]{%
  \global\@namedef{label@store@content@#2}{#3}%
  \begin{#1}%
  \label{#2}%
  #3%
  \end{#1}}
\newcommand\labelget[1]{\@nameuse{label@store@content@#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Test this first in \labelput{test1}{text mode}.

Does \labelget{test1} work?  % yes, it does

Test this again in math mode.

\begin{equation}\labelput{eq1}{e = mc^2}
\end{equation}

Now let us try to retrieve equation \ref{eq1} with
$\labelget{eq1}$   % the \ref works, but the \labelget fails silently


But the following works 
\labelenvput{equation}{eq2}{e = mc^3}

Retrieve
\[ \labelget{eq2} \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh crikey.... thanks. That's really obvious in hindsight.