# Is there a way to list every equation that you've labeled instead of just giving the number?

Tags: equations, cross-referencing

I have a document with a lot of equations throughout, and yes, I've labeled them, and yes, I know how to reference them, but when I reference them, I only get a number. Is there a way to do, for example something like`\ref{eq:Eqn1}` and it display `E=mc^2` instead of `1.1`? I don't necessarily want to override the number that `\ref` gives, but is there a function that displays the content instead?

This would be very helpful to me. I'm pretty new to Latex, and I haven't been able to find this feature elsewhere on the internet. Thank you!

Comment: This can help you: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/551148/270674

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/639110/can-i-merge-ref-and-nameref-into-one-command.